# android studio APK logcat issue

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, logcat

I have just downloaded the APK file of my Android Studio App, my phone is android but it is not compatible with using a USB to use the app on my phone.

Is there a way to use Logcat to find errors when using the APK set up on my phone.

There was a crash when using the app, but I need to see why.

Thanks, and apologies if my question is confusing.

Comment: you can use firebase crashlytics or you can create your own log file which will store in you device memory.

Comment: Consider using emulator of android

Comment: Your phone isn't an android? But you want to capture logcat on it?

Comment: @RituSumanMohanty good idea, i will see what that says!

Comment: @Steyrix I was using this, but speech recognition would not work on the emulator

Comment: @spartygw sorry, my phone is Android, my bad. It just is not compatible through USB

Comment: Gotcha. Well I think you have a couple options - you can use the AS emulator or you can write code in your app to capture logcat and share it (I do this in my app for debugging in the field) via email on startup.

Comment: Thank you for your advice @spartygw